# I want to fetch values of jquery dynamic radio button fields

Tags: jquery, html

here is the code

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>Service Charges</td>
      <td>Time Frame</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="uk">
      <td><input checked="checked" type="radio" name="shiping-method" id="shipping-method" value="1"></td>
      <td>uk</td>
      <td>free</td>
      <td>2-4 working days</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="uk">
      <td><input type="radio" name="shiping-method" id="shipping-method" value="3"></td>
      <td>uk</td>
      <td>6.00</td>
      <td>next working day</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

these values are not accessible on the main page 
I am trying to use the following code

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: use event delegation if dynamically added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: im using "on" but its not working

Comment: `$('.table').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){});` Try this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in below way:-

```
$('.table').on('click','input[type="radio"]',function(){ 
   var value = $(this).val(); 
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Working example:-

```js
$('.table').on('click','input[type="radio"]',function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
     alert($(this).val());

});

$('.clickMe').click(function(){
$("<tr class='uk'><td><input checked='checked' type='radio' name='shiping-method' id='shipping-method' value='1'></td><td>uk</td><td>free</td><td>2-4 working days</td></tr><tr class='uk'><td><input type='radio' name='shiping-method' id='shipping-method' value='3'></td><td>uk</td><td>6.00</td><td>next working day</td></tr>").insertAfter($('.table tbody tr'));

});
```

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Check</td>
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>Service Charges</td>
      <td>Time Frame</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="button" class="clickMe" value="ClickMe!">
```